# Jetpack compose overlay state

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I have button inside fragment that open compose overlay.

```
    private fun onClicked() {
    binding.composeView.setContent {
        cashDialogComposableView()
    }
}
```

What i want to do is to create a compose view that handle the overlay states itself .. no need for anything to call this overlay as simple as calling this line cashDialogComposableView and pass the overlay model.

so this the compose screen code:

```
@Composable
fun cashDialogComposableView() {
val cashDialogViewModel: CashDialogViewModel = viewModel()
cashDialogViewModel.changeCashDialogVisibility(true)

when (cashDialogViewModel.cashDialogVisibility.collectAsState().value) {
    true -> {
        cashDialogScreen(
            cashDialogModel = CashDialogModel(
                title = "",
                subtitle = "",
                confirmButtonAction = {},
                cancelButtonAction = {},
                icon = R.drawable.error_icon
            )
        ) {
            cashDialogViewModel.changeCashDialogVisibility(false)
        }
    }
    false -> {
        return
    }
}
}
```

When user click on the button it call this method .. and the first state is true .. and when the user dismiss the overlay it will change the state to false and the overlay will hide. and when the user click again the first line is change state to true .. but this is not happened .. what happened is when the user click on dismiss the state change and then the screen recompose and call again `cashDialogViewModel.changeCashDialogVisibility(true)`  this line so after the overlay hidden he shown again .

I tried a lot of things like LaunchedEffect and DisposableEffect and a lot of things . how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Trying to understand what you are saying. The first time the user clicks the button, the overlay is shown. Then user dismisses the overlay and it is indeed dismissed. Then, when the user clicks the button a second time, the overlay is not displayed?

Comment: No in my code solution
1- when user call the method it shown. 
2- if he dismissed it .. the overlay closed 
but in my code because of this line cashDialogViewModel.changeCashDialogVisibility(true) the overlay shown again after dismiss .. and i put this code because i need to change the state to true every time i click on this method .

Comment: Why do you need to set it to true to begin with? Why not have it as true in the first place in the view model?

Comment: No problem but when the user click ? i dont want to inject viewmodel any place just inside this compose screen